# How do I have the Customer column ignore the space and comma if U.LastName is null?

Tags: sql

I've tried a few different ways, including IF and CASE statements, but I just can't quite figure it out...

```
SELECT     U.Login AS Login, U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName AS Customer, 
        cast(cast(IsNull(sum(O.BillAmount), 0) as decimal(19,5)) as float) AS 'Total Billing', 
        MIN(O.DateOrderCreated) AS 'First Order',                        
        MAX(O.DateOrderCreated) AS 'Last Order' 
FROM  Orders O 
INNER JOIN    Store S ON S.StoreID = O.StoreID 
INNER JOIN    fn_UserStores(@ActiveUserId,12) US ON S.StoreId = US.StoreId 
INNER JOIN    Users U ON U.UserID = O.UserID 
WHERE     (O.IsCart = 0) AND (U.StatusID <> 2) AND (O.IsSaveForLater = 0) 
GROUP BY U.Login, U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName ORDER BY U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName
```

Comment: Will do next time. Thanks!

Comment: Or you can edit :^). http://i.stack.imgur.com/sDy36.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT  Login,
        Customer,
        [Total Billing],
        [First Order],
        [Last Order]
FROM
(
    SELECT  U.Login AS Login, 
            CASE WHEN U.LastName IS NOT NULL 
                THEN U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName 
                ELSE U.FirstName 
            END AS Customer, 
            cast(cast(IsNull(sum(O.BillAmount), 0) as decimal(19,5)) as float) AS 'Total Billing', 
            MIN(O.DateOrderCreated) AS 'First Order',                        
            MAX(O.DateOrderCreated) AS 'Last Order' 
    FROM  Orders O 
    INNER JOIN    Store S ON S.StoreID = O.StoreID 
    INNER JOIN    fn_UserStores(@ActiveUserId,12) US ON S.StoreId = US.StoreId 
    INNER JOIN    Users U ON U.UserID = O.UserID 
    WHERE     (O.IsCart = 0) AND (U.StatusID <> 2) AND (O.IsSaveForLater = 0) 
) X
GROUP BY Login, Customer 
ORDER BY Customer
```

Comment: When I tried it, I still get a "Report generation failed. Please check parameters." Although the first code block runs just fine.

Comment: Use double quotes for your multi word aliases.

Answer (score 1):

The coalesce function should work.  Change this:

```
U.LastName + ', ' + U.FirstName AS Customer
```

to this:

```
coalesce(U.LastName + ', ', '') + U.FirstName AS Customer
```

Make a similar change in your group by clause.